# How to add "1+More" tag button in jquery autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have added jquery autocomplete in my website search box for the locations. I am able to achieve multiple autocomplete search suggestions in the box but it looks not user friendly as all the suggestions are displayed with the box. I want 1 or 2 suggestions and rest all will be under the tag button called: "1+ More". I have attached the desired output and what I have right now.

Javascript code used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $.getJSON("<?php echo base_url();?>package.json", function(data) {
        
        autoComplete = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
            autoComplete.push(data[i]);
        }
        $('#myAutocompleteMultiple').autocomplete({
            source: autoComplete,
            multiselect: true,
            
        });
    });
</script>
```

and html used:

```
<input id="myAutocompleteMultiple" type="text" placeholder="Search Location"/>
```

Json file content:

```
[
    "Al Barari Commercial",
    "Al Quoz Commercial",
    "Al Qusais Commercial",
    "Arjan Commercial",
    "Bur Dubai Commercial"
]
```

Please anyone help me.

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbzJZ.png)

[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ4E2.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please anyone help.